# MySQL multiple ORDER BY based on condition

Tags: mysql

I had a query as follows which worked when I'm ordering the table only by `end_time`:

**WORKS**

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... ORDER BY field(table1.status, 'c1','a1', 'b1', 'e1',
'd1') asc, IF(table1.status = 'f1', table1.end_time, '') asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

But, if I want to add one more column to the conditional ordering, like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... ORDER BY field(table1.status, 'c1', 'a1', 'b1', 'e1',
'd1') asc, IF(table1.status = 'f1', (table1.end_time, table1.start_time), '') asc
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

It gives me:

> ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

But, the following query without **IF**, works:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... ORDER BY field(table1.status, 'c1', 'a1', 'b1', 'e1',
'd1') asc, table1.end_time, table1.start_time asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

How can I achieve the same query as above with **IF**

Comment: Looks like you are missing a function like DATE_SUB or something in ```(table1.end_time, table1.start_time)```

Comment: @SloanThrasher To be frank, the fields can be anything as per requirement, it's not restricted with DATE field. I may like to get it sorted by `end_time` & `name`, my intention is to get that query to work with **IF**

Comment: But, as the ```true``` result, your expression makes no sense. Two fields inside parentheses isn't a valid expression. to get it to work with the if expression, the if expression has to have valid syntax. Yours do not have valid syntax, specifically two columns separated by commas.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to order by `table1.start_time` as well when `table1.status = 'f1'`, you just need to add another IF:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE ... 
ORDER BY field(table1.status, 'c1','a1', 'b1', 'e1','d1') asc,
    IF(table1.status = 'f1', table1.end_time, '') asc,
    IF(table1.status = 'f1', table1.start_time, '') asc
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

Comment: Oh dear, you typed just a bit faster than me...But, thanks anyways. So, it's not possible with-in the same IF block?

Comment: Happens to me all the time! But I should get bonus points for making the query look pretty! :)

Comment: In response to your question in the first comment, no, unless you can figure out some way of combining the two variables such that sorting on that combination is the same as sorting on the two variables independently. With strings of the same length (and possibly dates), a `CONCAT` could work. With numbers, multplying the first by a power of 10 larger than any possible second value and then adding the second value could work too.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, it's ugly as it repeats code, but, I'm still expecting better answers:

For now, I solved my issue like:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ... ORDER BY field(table1.status, 'c1', 'a1', 'b1', 'e1', 'd1') asc,
IF(table1.status = 'f1', table1.end_time, '') asc,
IF(table1.status = 'f1', table1.start_time, '') asc
LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```